# Getting invalid HTTP method/URL pair Error when trying to load Firebase Storage Image URL into meta tag

Tags: html, firebase, firebase-storage, whatsapp, meta-tags

I am trying to include an image in my `og:image` meta tag that loads the image of a specific shop dynamically that is being shared by a user that is using my app when he wants to share the shop through WhatsApp so that it would show a thumbnail with the title, description, and image of the shop.

but it doesn't load so I went and opened developer tools and inspected the element of my meta tag I found that the URL leads to this error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Invalid HTTP method/URL pair."
  }
}
```

here is my code:

landing page of the shared link:

```
    <meta property="og:title" content="<?php echo $_GET["title"]; ?>" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="<?php echo $_GET["desc"]; ?>"/>
    <meta property="og:type" content="website"/>
    <meta property="og:url"  content=""/>
    <meta property="og:image" content ="<?php  echo $_GET["img"];?>"
```

Sent URL:

```
https://MyWebsiteName.com/share/?shop=xJbOcJDm1EOAkQdj0P3Q&title=Sorso&desc=Proudly%20Serving%20Gardelli%20Specialty%20Coffees&img=https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/myappname-9ff0f.appspot.com/o/Profile%20Image%2FxJbOcJDm1EOAkQdj0P3Q%2F125819259_2799019546979252_3099556570327477479_n.jpeg?alt=media&token=10450a78-d240-4f88-bb47-e809f91937c6
```

meta tag inspection:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/myappname-9ff0f.appspot.com/o/Profile Image/xJbOcJDm1EOAkQdj0P3Q/125819259_2799019546979252_3099556570327477479_n.jpeg?alt=media"/>
```

What's the problem and how can I load the firebase storage image URL correctly into the meta tag?

EDIT:

including firebase storage token in the url passed but still getting the same error:

```
{
      "error": {
        "code": 400,
        "message": "Invalid HTTP method/URL pair."
      }
    }
<meta property="og:title" content="<?php echo $_GET["title"]; ?>" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="<?php echo $_GET["desc"]; ?>"/>
    <meta property="og:type" content="website"/>
    <meta property="og:url"  content="<?php echo $_GET["img"].""."&token=".$_GET["token"]; ?>"/>
    <meta property="og:image" content ="<?php echo $_GET["img"].""."&token=".$_GET["token"];?>"/>
```

i believe the problem is that the meta tag is converting the encoding for "/" symbol from %2F to "/" and thats why it is invalid. how do i make the meta tag not do that for my url?

Comment: So, you have a file stored on Cloud Storage and you would like to obtain a public url shareable? Correct?

Comment: @MattiaGalati yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recently I had a similar problem, and must save the picture through the backend and provide a public persistent url; after some reserch found this great article:

https://www.sentinelstand.com/article/guide-to-firebase-storage-download-urls-tokens

### If the url should be generated at server-side

Basically, if the url is invalid (which could lead to the 400 error you posted) the issue could be related to the **token** url param: when you upload a file to Cloud Storage (don't know if also manually but surely with the SDK libraries) your file obtain automatically a token which is stored in the "**firebaseStorageDownloadTokens**" metadata key.

[image: GCP Console file metadata]

The correct public url could be generated with client SDK libraries, but server SDK seems not have the same feature (at least not all).

If you build your url adding this token then you should be able to publicly access your image.
In the article I linked above there is an example in NodeJS, and I adepted the code to my needs (Golang)

```golang
func CreatePersistentDownloadUrl(
    ctx context.Context,
    object *gcs.ObjectHandle,
) (string, error) {

    attrs, err := object.Attrs(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }

    token, ok := attrs.Metadata["firebaseStorageDownloadTokens"]
    if !ok {
        return "", errors.New("file token not found")
    }

    parsedName := url.QueryEscape(object.ObjectName())

    return fmt.Sprintf(
        "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/%s/o/%s?alt=media&token=%s",
        object.BucketName(),
        parsedName,
        token,
    ), nil
}
```

The relevant parts on the code are 2:

1. After the file is uploaded, fetch it's attributes and metadata in order to retrieve the assigned token
2. Build your url in the form *"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/**[bucket]**/o/**[file]**?alt=media&token=**[token]**"*

Don't forget to URL encode the file name!

### If the url should be generated at client-side

Tht said, the client SDK libraries should be able to generate such url without manually fetching the file metadata, but if the url is invalid, you should first check the url itself, and verify the result with a browser, and then check if the problem could be the php parsing of the querystring.

Let's pretend your client generated an url formed like this and you already checked the url for correctness (note that the following url is already somewhat encoded, see the space encoded as "*%20*"):

```
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/myappname-9ff0f.appspot.com/o/Profile%20Image/xJbOcJDm1EOAkQdj0P3Q/125819259_2799019546979252_3099556570327477479_n.jpeg?alt=media&token=10450a78-d240-4f88-bb47-e809f91937c6
```

before passing that URL to server I would encode like this in Javascript:

```js
encodeURIComponent(url);

// Which gives you this
// https%3A%2F%2Ffirebasestorage.googleapis.com%2Fv0%2Fb%2Fmyappname-9ff0f.appspot.com%2Fo%2FProfile%2520Image%2FxJbOcJDm1EOAkQdj0P3Q%2F125819259_2799019546979252_3099556570327477479_n.jpeg%3Falt%3Dmedia%26token%3D10450a78-d240-4f88-bb47-e809f91937c6
```

Now on the server-side you decode the querystring value to re-obtain the url:

```php
$url = urldecode($_GET['img']);

// You should get this
// https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/myappname-9ff0f.appspot.com/o/Profile%20Image/xJbOcJDm1EOAkQdj0P3Q/125819259_2799019546979252_3099556570327477479_n.jpeg?alt=media&token=10450a78-d240-4f88-bb47-e809f91937c6
```

Comment: the thing is, is that i am including the token from the firebase storage and yet it still gives me this error {
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Invalid HTTP method/URL pair."
  }
}

Comment: i believe the problem is that the meta tag is converting the encoding for "/" symbol from %2F to "/" and thats why it is invalid. how do i make the meta tag not do that for my url?

Comment: Generally speaking, if you are sure the URL works when it's generated from the client, you should URLEncode it in order to safely send it to the PHP page. In this way you ensure that the webserver will not broke it. When the url arrives on PHP, the you can decode it and use the value in the meta-tag

Comment: can you please give me an example code of what you said? i think it will solve my problem.

Comment: I've added some examples in my reply. Please check and tell me if they are clear and solved your doubts.

Comment: thank you so much for your answer, my problem is still not solved and i actually already tried what you just included. still thank you for the reply.

Comment: I will be glad to further help you if you provide more context, like the actual url and the php code you are using to parse the querystring.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem in my axios. Instead of passing the data with ?={url} use json instead. Passing the data with ?={url} converts strings in the URL "%2F" to "/"

Comment: Adrian, you might want to [format your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) correctly to help future readers. If you have some more details on exactly how to "*use json instead*", this might also be valuable.